# Hybris ImpEx - how to export hero products

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice, impex

I want to write a script that exports in a .csv file all Products that have been boosted via the Adaptive Search perspective in SAP Backoffice. However, I'm not sure how to do this as the Product being boosted or not is not an actual attribute I can use in my SELECT statement for the export.

Tried looking for some sort of indicator in the Administration tab of a boosted product, but it's no different from any other product. The only alternative I see is to manually go through all the boosted products, but that's very inefficient